# Returning null value when i am trying to delete in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Controller.java**

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteRow(@RequestParam("vehicleNo") int vehicleNo) {
        userService.deleteRow(vehicleNo);
        System.out.println("delete... " + vReg.getVehicleNo());
        return ("/dashboard");
    }

}
```

**DaoImpl**

```
 public void deleteRow(Integer vehicleNo) {
    String Sql = null;
    Sql = "delete from vehiclereg where vehicleNo= " + vehicleNo;
    jdbcTemplate.update(Sql, vehicleNo);
    System.out.println("Deleted Record with vehicleNo = " + vehicleNo);
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: First of all you better have to use `RequestMethod.DELETE` for _delete_ actions.
In DAO also is a wrong code - you concatenate parameter to the SQL and then call `jdbcTemplate.update` with this parameter, but it is already in the _Sql_ string. Try to invoke `jdbcTemplate.update(Sql)` without parameter.
Or you can pass it to the _jdbcTempalte_ but in this case do not concatenate them to the _Sql_
`Sql ="delete from vehiclereg where vehicleNo=  ?";
jdbcTemplate.update(Sql, vehicleNo);`

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to passing 2 arguments to this function. Try this one...

```
jdbcTemplate.update(Sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

same value returning,

JSP HomePage

```
<table  id="myTable"  border="1" cellspacing="10" >
                        <thead align="center" >
                            <tr>
                                <th data-priority="6">ID</th>
                                <th data-priority="5">Owner Name</th>
                                <th data-priority="4">Vehicle No</th>
                                <th data-priority="3">License No.</th>
                                <th data-priority="2">Address</th>
                                <th data-priority="1">Pollution Date </th>
                                <th data-priority="6">Action</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <c:forEach var="vreg" items="${vRegList}" varStatus="loop">

                        <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">${loop.index+ 1}</th>
                                <td>${vreg.fullname}</td>
                                <td>${vreg.vehicleNo}</td>
                                <td>${vreg.licenceNo}</td>
                                <td>${vreg.address}</td>
                                <td>${vreg.date3}</td>
                                <td> <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href=edit?vehicleNo=${vreg.vehicleNo}></a> |

                                    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" href="delete?vehicleNo=${vreg.vehicleNo}"></a>|
                                   <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"  href="sms"></a>   </td>         
                            </tr>
    </tbody>
```